# Applying fuzzy logic to determine the degree to which a project is complete

Tags: average, fuzzy-logic

I have a Project made up of tasks.
Each task has an estimated completion percentage.

I realise I could treat each tasks completion percentage as a representation of the degree of membership to the fuzzy set "complete tasks" and the incomplete percentage as the degree of memebership to the fuzzy set of "incomplete tasks"

e.g

complete {T1 .80, T2 .73, T3 .0, T4 1.0}

incomplete {T1 .20, T2 .23, T3 1.0, T4 .0}

How would I calculate the degree to which all tasks are complete (sum of all tasks = project so the project completeness) ? ?

Would this be the same as the average task completion e.g. sum(completion) / number of tasks?

N.B not strictly homework, I'm writing the program that handles the projects for an assignment and want to make sure the logic I code is correct.

Comment: In the complete tasks, what does T1 .80 mean?

Comment: Sorry. T represented the task, so task 1, task 2 etc, and the decimal representing the degree of membership to that fuzzy set

Comment: Isn't the degree to which the task is complete = the percentage of work done so far in task? Say I did 60% of the program, that is the same as the task is 60% complete?

Comment: Thats correct, I'm interested in finding out how complete the whole project is. I'm also curious as to whether this would be the same as average completeion of a task or not.

Comment: if the degree to which the task is complete = the percentage of work done, then your tasks in the complete set should be: T1.100, T2.100,etc.

Comment: I'm not concerned with the tasks, they only have one value, its the total completeness of the project (that is made up of these tasks) I'm interested in determining. I'd like to know if this is the same as the average task completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to know if this is the same as the average task completion
>   Yes, it would be if:

1-The sum of tasks cover the entire project activities in other words, Project = Task1 and Task2 and .... and TaskN

2-The average completion, based on the completion % of each task, is valid indicator only if (1) is true and if all the task have equal weight, otherwise the average may not show the truth.

Comment: 1- True. I should have explained this better 2- Yes in this case true so accepted :) can you point me in the direction of where I could learn about introducing a weighting to the tasks and the impact this would have, I think the only real weighting I could introduce in this particular case would be a priority to each task, meaning higher priority tasks would have a greater weighting towards project completion than those with lower priorities.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your suggestion of priority may be OK (it depends on your choice). Please check this link it might have some value: http://www.mofeel.net/894-microsoft-public-project/18871.aspx